# Are booleans overwritten in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def space_check(board, position):  
    return board[position] == ' '    

def full_board_check(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if space_check(board, i):
            return False
    return True
```

the last line is return True
why not `else: return True`
if the if statement returned false, won't the last `return True` overwrite it??

Comment: Because you can only return once.

Comment: you mean if it returns False the last line will not work?

Comment: The function returns True in the loop for any match, ending the function. If no if space_check... is True you hit the return False outside the loop. You could use `else: return True` but you don't have to as you only reach that return if no  if space_check... evaluated to True

Comment: please don't paste screenshots of code. Take the time to properly copy, paste and format the code for this site.

Comment: You can also simplify the code to `return any(check_space(board, i) for i in range(1, 10))` which would return True on any match or False for no matches just like your own code. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Comment: this is not what the code does though

Comment: @user3684792,  yes, `return not any(...`, not a big change and now identical to the OP's code.

Comment: don't think so, you don't want to return true if 'check_space' - this would imply the board is not full

Comment: It works now you changed it lol - my response was to your previous post before you edited it

Comment: bro - you edited it to that. I was replying to the sarcastic comment you left before you edited it when you realised you were wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if space_check(board, i):
         return False
    else:
         return True
```

then after the first iteration in the for loop the function would return. This would not lead the the expected behaviour. Currently, you check every space, and not just the first one

Comment: The return True is outside the loop, not in the loop.

Comment: Then why have you put it in the loop?

Comment: because this is what the op was asking no? 'the last line in that picture is (return True), why it is not (Else: return True)'. If the code was as the op suggested, then it would be wrong

Comment: You can have `else:return True` outside the loop where the else belongs to the for loop. The outside return is only reached if the if check never evaluates to True

Comment: oh, I misunderstood question then

Comment: It is not 100 percent clear from their wording but what they are completely misunderstanding is that you can only return once from a function so there is no notion of *booleans  being overwritten*

Comment: @user3684792 i understood why `return True` is out of the for loop...
to take all possibilities... but if the if statement returned False...why won't the last `return True` overwrite it?

Comment: no, because the function returns, so the last line is never executed

Comment: @user3684792 Thanx